# Как сохранить значение select при обновлении страницы?

Tags: php, html, mysql

При релоаде страницы значение select не сохраняется. 7-ой час уже пытаюсь сделать, но как видно, без толку.

```html
echo "<select id='dropdown' name='dropdown' onchange='top.location=this.value'>";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_row($students_result))
{
  echo "<option value='http://exam/?students_id=$line[0]'>";
  echo " <a href = '?students_id=".$line[0]."' style = 'color:blue'> ".$line[1]." ".$line[2]." </a> ";
  echo "</option>";
}
echo "</select>"; echo "</div>";
```

Весь код, если понадобится, лежит здесь - [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/4qstT3S1)

Comment: что значит не сохраняется? а куда оно должно сохранятся? и почему оно должно сохраняться по вашему мнению?

Comment: Код предоставленный мой чистый, т.е. я решил не показывать вам мои попытки реализовать сохранение значения select

Answer (score 0):

Значения селекта будут лежать в массиве `$_POST`, в случае сабмита формы. У вас же простой редирект на линк указанный в опции селекта.А уже student_id можно будет вытаскивать из массива `$_GET` после редиректа.

Comment: Форма же меняется onchange, я правильно понимаю? Будет ли массив $_POST пополняться при onchange?

Comment: По onchange у вас не отправляется форма,просто считывается значение опции и делается редирект,получить значение опции как я и говорил сможете из массива GET. А POST в вашем случаем не пополняется

Answer (score -2):

У select признак выбора какого то option, это тэг selected, так?
Ну и потом, после перезагрузки смотрим значение name='dropdown' и потом условия

```
if({name} eq "1") {
<select name='dropdown'>
         <option value=1 selected>Вариант 1</option>
         <option value=2>Вариант 2</option>
         <option value=3>Вариант 3</option>
       </select>
}
ElsIf ({name} eq "3") {
<select name='dropdown'>
         <option value=1>Вариант 1</option>
         <option value=2>Вариант 2</option>
         <option value=3 selected>Вариант 3</option>
       </select>
}
```

и т.д. Я так делал.